# How to "inspect element" on scrollbar?

Tags: css, google-chrome, webkit, google-chrome-devtools

With webkit, it is possible to modify scrollbar styles. However, i cannot "inspect element" on scrollbar when debugging in chrome. Is there any workaround for this?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Inspect the element you are interested in seeing the style of the scroll bar and go to the bottom of the "Styles" section. You will find the definitions of the pseudo elements